# Distance from a tangent to a circle given radian

Tags: geometry

Sorry about the title, I find it very hard to describe my intention concisely.

Let there be a circle with radius $R$, and a point that is strictly outside of the circle, the distance from the point to the circle is $h$, $h$ is strictly greater than $0$.

Construct a Cartesian coordinate system so that the origin is at the center of the circle, and the $x$-axis coincides with the segment between aforementioned point and the center of the circle.

Now draw two lines from the point that are tangent to the circle.

[image]

I want an equation that relates the radian $\theta$ to the distance between two points on the line that is x-axis rotated $\theta$ radians counterclockwise around the origin, one of the two points being the intersect between the aforementioned line and the circle, the other being the intersect between the line and one of the tangents.

The output of the equation should be $h$ at $\theta = 0$ and $\infty$ at $\theta = \pi$. Because of the nature of tangents, there are right triangles, using the definition of trigonometric functions we get $0$ points:

$$\pm \arcsin(\frac{\sqrt{(R + h) ^ 2 - R^2}}{R+h})=\pm\arcsin(\frac{\sqrt{2Rh+h^2}}{R+h})$$

I have tried to derive the equations but I am a high-school dropout and mathematics was never my strong point.

Anyway the angle between the tangents and the x-axis would be $\pm\arcsin(\frac{R}{R+h})$, so that the slope would be $\tan(\arcsin(\frac{R}{R+h}))$, and then using a simple trigonometric identity the slope is:

$$\pm\frac{\frac{R}{R+h}}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{R}{R+h})^2}}$$

And equations for the tangents would be:

$$y = \frac{\frac{R}{R+h}}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{R}{R+h})^2}}(x - R - h)
\\ y = -\frac{\frac{R}{R+h}}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{R}{R+h})^2}}(x - R - h)$$

If:

$$k = -\frac{\frac{R}{R+h}}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{R}{R+h})^2}}$$

Then we have equation $k (x - R - h) = \tan(\theta)x$, then:

$$x = \frac{k(R + h)}{k - \tan(\theta)}$$

And $y = \tan(\theta)x$, and then using parametric equation of a circle:

$$y_1 = R \cdot \sin(\theta) \\ x_1 = R \cdot \cos(\theta)$$

And distance equation we get:

$d = \sqrt{(x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2}$

The function should be symmetric, there would be a local maximum at $\theta=0$, then in both directions the function would decrease for a bit, until it reaches zero at $\pm\arcsin(\frac{\sqrt{2Rh+h^2}}{R+h})$ and then the function would rapidly increase until it reaches every odd multiples of $\pi$, at which the value is $\infty$, then the value decreases and the cycle repeats.

---

I have solved the problem, turns out I used the wrong sign, the tangent used should have a negative slope if the line passing through the origin is $\tan(\theta)x$.

Anyway after I flipped the sign the problem is fixed. But as you can see there are lots of steps involved, I wonder if there are simpler equations I can use so that I can do all these in less steps.

---

### Edit

Actually the function is multistage, and it reaches infinity before antipolar point. Specifically the function reaches infinity at the same angle that is the slope of the tangents, because they are parallel and will never intersect.

Angles between $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and the tangent slope do intersect with the tangents, but the intersection point is on the other side of the circle, the ray from the center never crosses the tangents, so the function is also infinity.

Comment: This posting could really benefit from a diagram.  For help managing an image, see the Images section, at the bottom of 
[this article](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and see also 
[this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/recommendation-enhance-the-mathse-html-markdown-help-article-re-images).  Please embed the image directly into your posting.  Also, please delete all of your computer code from this posting.  If you need help debugging programming code, you might look for a programming oriented stack exchange forum.